# What is better in performance: Jetty or Tomcat for production needs?

Tags: tomcat, jetty, performance

im planning to use java/jsp for web application installed on virtual web hosting space
i know tomcat very well but i keep reading about jetty that is small and fast
what to you think from your experience about the two ?
what is better ?
i will use Nginx for static pages .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind though that those tests mentioned by spender are pretty old, for example they are using Jetty 4.2.20 (latest version is 8.0.0.M0), so a lot has probably changed since then. I can't seem to find any reliable current tests on google but I do remember reading articles that basically said that nowadays the performance gap has narrowed.

Although they are not detailed performance test these articles have some relevant information:

- http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/jetty_vs_tomcat_vs_resin
- http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/google-chose-jetty

Comment: Also jetty's modular and configurable design are an advantage in a virtual hosted environment, basically you can easily remove all the features you don't need to lower your footprint. I have been using jetty to power my blog and other sites, though I dont't have much traffic yet so I can't help with numbers regarding performance under stress.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that with Jetty you can actually have the web server embedded into your application, which for some users can be extremely practical, but probably won't suit a project that is large.

It's not as fully featured as other options (incl. Tomcat), but as you mention it is small and fast.  If you can see advantages of embedding it and it's a small project, use it.